# Find all columns with different values for two rows in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table from which two entries in particular from which I am looking for differences.  This table has enough columns that I'd like a way to have it only display the different ones.  I would like to identify which column values for those two entries are different.  That is -

```
table_one
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| key_id | order_number | serial_code | order_date | idk_more_data_one | idk_more_data_two |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0000  |     45576    |    f56b22   |  20200101  |       22000       |        99.4       |
|  0001  |     45576    |    f56b22   |  20200101  |       23000       |        91.7       |
|  0002  |     45577    |    rt1000   |  20200101  |       19500       |        93.3       |
|  0003  |     45577    |    rt1000   |  20200101  |       20000       |        93.3       |
|  0004  |     45577    |    rt1000   |  20200101  |       19750       |        93.3       |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I would need a query that pulls out just the `key_id` values of `0000` and `0001`, and then only displays columns `key_id`, `idk_more_data_one`, and `idk_more_data_two`, because they are the only columns that changed.

I saw online people talking about self joins and the like but I don't think that's what I want or if it is then I do not understand how to use it properly here, and it wasn't exactly the same issue so I wasn't able to transplant it directly.  I also tried something very direct, like

```
Select *
From
    (Select *
    From table_one
    Where order_number = '45576')
Where
```

but couldn't puzzle out what would yield me the right effect in the `Where` portion of the statement.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Uh...how do I know which one I have?  I'm using it in MS SQL Server Management Studio, does that mean it's sqlserver?  Happy to update the tags, I just...don't know?

Comment: Do you want to compare only Key id 0000 and 0001? or you want to compare records for each key with every other for the same order number?

Comment: Just those two, I just wanted to illustrate that the table has more than those two in it and I am only picking those two rows out of it.  Apologies if the the extra information was more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what are you looking to, but if you are trying to search 2 registries by and key_id and those 3 fields:

```
SELECT key_id, idk_more_data_one, idk_more_data_two 
FROM table_one 
WHERE key_id IN ("0000","0001")
```

EDITION AFTER COMMENTARY:

What you are trying to do is build a custom query, there are probably more ways to do this but I'll write what I've done and I hope it will help you.

First of all you'll have to create and storedProcedure (SP) for this kind of queries, the SP will have to accept at least one parameter that will be a varchar of N length (as much as you think it may do) and will contain the columns you are going to be queriing.

Then you'll have to construct your query as an string to which you'll concatenate your parameters:

```
ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE sp_whatevername
@columns varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    @DECLARE Query varchar(500)
    SET Query = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM tbl_one'
    EXEC (Query)
END
```

As I said, this may not be the best approach due to the use of "EXEC" which in mssql may do harm if is incorrectly used and you have to be very careful with what you allow to get to your db because you'll be opening one big open door there.

So, to append you where statement, you'll have to do the same appending to it the `WHERE` in front of the statetment

```
ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE sp_whatevername
@columns varchar(200),
@where varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    @DECLARE Query varchar(500)
    SET Query = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM tbl_one ' + @where
    EXEC (Query)
END
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't know what columns idk_more_data_one and idk_more_data_two are going to be.  Just to throw out some numbers, there are thirty columns, and perhaps three of them will be different...but I don't know *which* columns are different.  I would need some `Select [term dependent on the Where term]`.

Comment: Oh, I see now, there is a way but is not the best approach but maybe the only one that I know and I had to implemented once or twice, I'll write it down and I'll let you know (well stack will haha)